# Limit the visibility of number of lines shown in text long area fields

Tags: apex, long-text-area

This is how I see the text long area field in Standard layout in salesforce. How can I limit the visibility of it to 3 lines and to provide the option to the user to expand it. Is there any way to achieve it in Salesforce.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write custom visual force page to achieve this kind of functionality. Salesforce does not support to view excrete of data or visible only some selected lines.

You can create a custom field and populate the n (number of lines) lines from long text field by creating trigger.

> Field Definition Configurations #Visible Lines: The number of lines option on the field is only taken into account in edit mode only and will display all available line in detail mode.

I hope this information will help!!

Comment: Visible lines option only support when you are going to edit the record, not when you are viewing the record on detail page. It displays whole content.

Comment: You are correct - Another example of how common sense says it should be one way yet the implementation of it is the exact opposite.

Answer (score -1):

There is point and click option in Field Definition Configurations **#Visible Lines**:

[image]

Comment: Visible lines option only support when you are going to edit the record, not when you are viewing the record on detail page.

Comment: @TheAjayGupta i didn't notice that. Will delete anw.